# How to change SimpleAdapter to ArrayAdapter in android?

Tags: android, adapter

I have code for simpleAdapter as bellow. I want change it to ArrayAdapter.

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    com_list.this, contactList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME,TAG_CURRENT_BID,TAG_MINIMUM_BID,
                            TAG_END_TIME }, new int[] { R.id.name,R.id.current_bid,R.id.minimum_bid,
                             R.id.end_time });

            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: have you tried this ? public ArrayAdapter (Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every ArrayAdaper can bind a SINGLE TextView to SINGLE object. As your code implies, there are 4 TextViews, so you need to use 4 ArrayAdapter instances.

It works like below:

```
adapterName = new ArrayAdapter(com_list.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.name, names);
adapterCBid = new ArrayAdapter(com_list.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.current_bid, cbids);
adapterMBid = new ArrayAdapter(com_list.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.minimum_bid, mbids);
adapterEndTime = new ArrayAdapter(com_list.this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.end_time, endtimes);
```

`names`, `cbids`, `mbids`, `endtimes` stand for the corresponding values in your `contactList`

As with Filter, you can refer to the source code of [ArrayFilter](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayFilter) and [SimpleFilter](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.java#SimpleFilter), both ones use space to split the original value so you can not use space as search keyword. You can inherit  SimpleAdapter（override `getFilter()`） to implement your own Filter.

Comment: how to add  setListAdapter(?);

Comment: It seems that it if want to use ArrayAdapter you should also  separate the  listview ，each listview should only contains item that has only one Textview.

Comment: Please check complete file https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7fe8b8b68343143699f6

Comment: My problem is SimpleAdapter getfilter is searching sequentially. Not searching ,if I add space. I think, it can be avoid by using ArrayAdapter . Do you have any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Not searching, if I add space"?

Comment: You mean you can not use space as a search keyword?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69191/discussion-between-jobcrazy-and-arshid-kk).